# Nedarim to d’rabbanan prohibitions

Tags: halacha, nedarim-shevuot, derabanan, tractate-nedarim, masechet-shevuot

If one makes a Neder to do something that is prohibited D’rabbanan, and knows that it is prohibited D’rabbanan, is it considered a Neder in vain, or is one nonetheless still considered obligated to do the thing that is normally D’rabbanan prohibited?

Comment: https://www.kipa.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91/%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%A8-%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%92%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94/ לסיכום: מי שנשבע נגד מצווה דאורייתא או נשבע לעבור על לאיסור דרבנן, לא צריך לעשות התרה מפני שהדברים לא חלים.

מי שנשבע או נדר להמנע ממצוות עשה דרבנן (לא להדליק נר חנוכה; לא ליטול ידיים לסעודה) צריך התרה.

Comment: English translation please?

Comment: He says that if you make a *neder* not to do a *mitzvah de'rabannan* the *neder* is *chal*, I assume the same applies if you make a *neder* to do an *issur de'rabannan*.

Comment: What is a neder in vain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While talking about נדרים, THAT’S NOT A נדר! Since a נדר is on an object not an action. But let’s say you DID do it on an object of course it works, it works on a דאורייתא! https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Nedarim.2.2?lang=bi
And by שבועות it’ll also work, since the only reason that they don’t work דאורייתא, is since we made a שבועה at Har Sinai to observe the Mitzvos. https://www.sefaria.org/Shevuot.27a.3?lang=bi
There’s a better proof out there, just forgot where.
This is still a good proof though.